# Let $Y= \prod_{j \in J}Y_j$. Show that maps $f,g:X\to Y$are homotopic if and only if $\pi_j \circ f \simeq \pi_j \circ g$ for all $j \in J$.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $Y= \prod_{j \in J}Y_j$. Show that maps $f,g:X\to Y$are homotopic if and only if $\pi_j \circ f \simeq \pi_j \circ g$ for all $j \in J$.

Fix $j \in J$ and suppose that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic. Then there exists $h: X \times I \to Y$ such that $h(x,0)=f(x)$ and $h(x,1)=g(x)$.

Define $h':= \pi_j \circ h$, then $h'(x,0)=\pi_j(h(x,0)) = \pi_j(f(x))$ and $h'(x,1)=\pi_j(h(x,1))=\pi_j(g(x))$ and since the projections are continous $h'$ is continuous and implies that $\pi_j \circ f \simeq \pi_j \circ g$.

I'm stuck with the other direction. If I suppose that $\pi_j \circ f \simeq \pi_j \circ g$, then I have the existence of a homotopy $h:X \times I \to Y_j$ such that $h(x,0)=\pi_j \circ f$ and $h(x,1)= \pi_j \circ g$. What I would like to say is that, then $h':X \times I \to Y$ could be defined as $h':=\pi_j^{-1} \circ \pi_j \circ h$, but I'm not sure if this is satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

By assumption for every $j\in J$ there exists an homotopy $h_j:X\times I\to Y_j$ such that $h_j(x,0)=(\pi_j\circ f)(x)$ and $h_j(x,1)=(\pi_j\circ g)(x)$ for every $x\in X$.
There exists one and only ony function $h:X\times I\to Y$ such that $h_j=\pi_j\circ h$ for every $j\in J$.
Moreover, $h$ is continuous and $h(x,0)=f(x)$, $h(x,1)=g(x)$ for every $x\in X$.

Comment: How does the existence of $h_j:X\times I\to Y_j$ for every $j$ imply that there exists $h:X\times I\to Y$?

Comment: Cannot I define $h: X \times I \to Y$ to be the map $$h(x,t)= (h_1(x,t), h_2(x,t), \dots)$$ and so $$h(x,0)=(f_1(x), f_2(x), \dots)$$ and $$h(x,1)=(g_1(x),g_2(x), \dots)?$$ This map is continuous as all the components are continous.

Comment: This follows from universal property of product.